# How to Use Way of White Circlet

Tags: dark-souls-3

At the beginning of the game, starting as a Knight, I have a usable item called "Way of White Circlet". Despite the name, you can't equip it as a headgear item, and it is unusable by default, regardless of whether I possess an Ember or not, though it can be equipped like a usable item.

Does anyone know what exactly this item does, and how to activate it? The exact item text implies it's a multi-use Ember:

> Online play item. Restore the connection to other worlds.
>
> Those who engage in unjust deeds when in contact with other worlds
>   will lose their connection to them.
>
> Way of White Circlets assume such sin as their own, but are found few
>   and far between. Acting without honor will never be without risk.

Comment: That text, as I read it (specifically the second paragraph) indicates that you can do things that cause you to lose the ability to play online even when you are kindled, and that this item can reverse that.

Comment: @murgatroid99 hm, good point, I didn't really read it that way. That's probably it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you repeatedly disconnect or otherwise go offline while being invaded, summon signs will no longer appear for you. However, you will still be available for invasions only now you can't summon phantoms to help you either with invasions or with bosses.

Much like the [Bone of Order](http://darksouls2.wikidot.com/bone-of-order) in Dark Souls 2, the Way of White Circlet is a way for you to restore that link, allowing you to see summon signs again.

Answer (score 1):

It's an item used if you get banned. You can use that item to get back into normal play, one of the item will spawn every 10 to 15 hours of gameplay at your coffin.